# SELECT de mês/ano em DATAS

Tags: sql, oracle

Eu preciso que o select me retorne todas as linhas que foram inseridas em julho de 2010, como mostra no exemplo, independente do dia. Como retornar essa consulta?

```
SELECT * FROM FRCAST 
WHERE DATA_ID = TO_CHAR('07-2010', 'mm-yyyy');
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Você pode usar a função [EXTRACT](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions050.htm) para testar pedaços de uma data. Sua consulta ficaria assim:

```
SELECT * FROM FRCAST 
WHERE extract(month from DATA_ID) = 7 and extract (year from DATA_ID) = 2010;
```

Comment: Bacana isso... não tinha pensado numa solução pra incluir o mês todo sem usar ``BETWEEN``. Toma um +1

Comment: Deixa minha resposta como uma alternativa abaixo, mas a resposta da Giuliana é mais elegante e legível.

Answer (score 1):

Você pode também usar o `BETWEEN`:

```
SELECT * FROM FRCAST 
WHERE DATA_ID between 
TO_DATE('01/07/2010','DD/MM/YYYY') and 
TO_DATE('31/07/2010 23:59:59','DD/MM/YYYY HH24:mi:ss');
```

Answer (score 0):

Para fazer esta consulta, você pode fazer da seguinte forma:

```
SELECT * FROM FRCAST
WHERE TO_CHAR(DATA_ID,'MM-YYYY')='07-2010';
```

<sub>Referências:
[How to select rows for a specific month](http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_select_rows_specific_month.htm)
[TO_CHAR (datetime)](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions180.htm)</sub>

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM FRCAST 
WHERE  TO_CHAR(DATA_ID, 'mm-yyyy') ='07-2010'
```